# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in Asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cannot run the application on my PC
I tried to fix this issue, but this issue comes to my PC only
and **found some fixed method in GOOGLE** Here link
*https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-error/*

I followed these steps whatever the link said, but no luck and also gave the issue details below

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: This question looks like a deliberate attempt to direct traffic to the linked site.  There's no code shown and no question asked.